# React Native: Yet another "Undefined is not an object (evaluating action.type)

Tags: ios, react-native, react-redux, create-react-native-app

I'm developing a CRNA application, however, the store connection is not working and I'm receiving the above error when creating the store.

**"Undefined is not an object (evaluating action.type)**

Searching for similar problems, I got to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43509679/react-native-redux-createstore-errorundefined-is-not-an-objectevaluating-acti), which is a reducer being called while passed to the `createStore` function, which is not my case.

And [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43668894/react-native-android-actions-error-undefined-is-not-an-object-evaluating-act#43668991), which is related to `AnalyticsTracker` called before an async dispatcher, also not my case.

Here's the minimum code to reproduce.

**App.js**

```
import React from 'react';
import {
  View,
  Text
} from 'react-native'; 
import { Provider } from 'react-redux';
import store from './store';

class App extends React.Component {

  render() {
    return (
      <Provider store={store}>
         <View>
            <Text>Hello</Text>
         </View>
      </Provider>
    );
  }
}
```

**store.js**

```
import { createStore, applyMiddleware } from 'redux';
import thunk from 'redux-thunk';

import reducer from './reducer';
// Here the error happens
export default createStore(reducer, applyMiddleware(thunk));
```

**reducer.js**

```
import actionTypes from './action_types';
const initialState = {
}

export default (action, state=initialState) => {
    // This is the top line on stacktrace
    switch (action.type) {
        case actionTypes.MY_ACTION:
            return state;
    }
    return state;
}
```

I have tried a few changes in my code, i.e: removing the middlewares.

Any idea why is it happening? Am I missing something?

Comment: If you remove your switch case, is it remove the error or not?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have noticed that your createStore call is false, since enhancers are passed as the third parameter. Change it to:

```
const store = createStore(persistedReducer, undefined, applyMiddleware(thunk));
```

Additionally the structure of your reducer is false. Your first parameter in your reducer should be the initialState followed by the action as the second parameter - this is why you get undefined is not an object!.

> As described in Reducers, it has to have a signature of (previousState, action) => newState, is known as a reducer function, and must be pure and predictable.

From:  https://redux.js.org/recipes/structuringreducers